# Groovy alternative for hash_hmac

Tags: groovy

Is there any Groovy alternative methods for generating a keyed hash value using the HMAC method? Example that php method as shown below:

```
hash_hmac( "sha256", "the data", "secret key" );
```

Comment: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/

Answer (score 0):

This groovy code works creates a HMAC SHA256 hash from a string:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

def hmac_sha256(String secretKey, String data) {
try {
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
    mac.init(secretKeySpec)
    return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes())
   } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Invalid key exception while converting to HMac SHA256")
  }


def x = hmac_sha256("secret", "my-data").encodeBase64().toString();
```